# How to efficiently use Python-style integers in Cython?

Tags: python, types, integer, cython, static-typing

I am working in Cython, and I need to use Python's `int` type, not C's `int` type. How do I declare a Cython variable to be a Python-style integer?

`cdef int x` will use a C-style integer, not a Python-style integer.

`cdef object x` can store a Python-style integer, but it will be slow due to redundant runtime type checking.

If I know 100% that an object is going to be an `int`, can I avoid the runtime type checks?

The [Cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html) seem to indicate that declaring it as `object` is the best that we can do, and we just have to live with the redundancy. This feels uncharacteristic of Cython, and I'm not fully convinced that I'm interpreting the documentation correctly.

Is is even possible to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types) are pretty clear (emphasis added):

> The Python types `int`, `long`, and `float` are not available for static typing and instead interpreted as C `int`, `long`, and `float` respectively, **as statically typing variables with these Python types has zero advantages.**

There are a number of concrete C APIs associated with stuff like `list`, `tuple`, etc., where static typing provides a meaningful benefit, allowing Cython to save time by compiling code that works with them on a more intrusive level (directly accessing the underlying array for `list` and `tuple` for example). For Python 3's `int` (and Python 2's `long`), that advantage largely doesn't exist; at best Cython could skip a *tiny* amount of type-checking work, in exchange for needing to reproduce all the rest of the code involved in the operations without those prechecks (Python 2's `int` is a C `long` under the hood, so you may as well declare it as such and benefit from using the raw C value directly). And it's quite a lot of code, given the complexities of working with arbitrary precision integers, and entirely unnecessary. If your values are small enough, you can use them as C types, but for anything larger, the cost of specializing for them would be greater than the gains.

In short: Declare it as nothing, or `object` if you want to be explicit. There's no benefit to be had from what you're trying to do, and you *can't* do it in any event.

Comment: currently, that paragraph has been rewritten somewhat radically in the same latest documentation link, but the rest of your answer seems to still hold in practice! it seems this is also an area of change at least in terms of the documentation, between cython 3.0 and 3.1